# Is it an obligatory or a obligatory

Tags: indefinite-article

I was wondering if "An" should be used with *obligatory* or "A". I understand that since *obligatory* begins with a vowel I should use "An" but I see people are using "A" more frequently than "An"

To me "A obligatory like" sounds right, as in "a Facebook like".

Also .. Is "and a obligatory comment" correct or is it "and an obligatory comment" ?

Comment: In what situations have you seen or heard this? It sounds most unnatural to me.

Comment: You see people use "a" more often than "an". I dare say that many, if not most, people see "an" used more often. As @tunny says, where do you see people use "a"? Don't forget that this "rule" about using "an" is not something someone made up; it's something people do because it is easier to _pronounce_ it that way. That is why native speakers will find the _difficult_ way, _a obligatory_ most unnatural: it is too hard to say!

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=a+obligatory

Normally I do a google search when I am confused and I found a lot of websites using A obligatory stop so I assumed it is correct.

Comment: Google is a most unreliable guide when it comes to the question of correctness of language.  Try using the *British National Corpus*, *The Corpus of Contemporary American Usage*, *The Corpus of Global Web-Based English*  or *Google books Ngram Viewer*.

Comment: _If_ you use google like this, a tip: do a search on ["an obligatory"](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22a%20obligatory%22&rct=j#q=%22an+obligatory%22) (619,000 results) versus ["a obligatory"](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22a%20obligatory%22&rct=j#q=%22a+obligatory%22) (53,000 results): mind the quotation marks and you'll see more reliable result. Also not that in the top results, "an" includes dictionaries and the like, whereas "a" yields top results from tripadvisor and similar sites where you find many non-natives leaving comments.

Comment: I assume you are talking about pronunciation, since you mention *sounds* right. Yes, it is true that many people use *a* in talking before words that start with vowel sounds, such as *a apple,* *a exploratory,* *a appliance.* This might be regional. It is not incorrect. But in writing, *an obligatory* is the way to go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To me only "an obligatory" sounds right. "a obligatory" is not only more difficult to pronounce but also sounds pretty odd (to me at least). [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20obligatory%2C%20a%20obligatory&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20obligatory%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20obligatory%3B%2Cc0) seems to agree with me:

[image: Google Ngram]

Comment: I agree. Sometimes one uses "an" even if the following word begins with a consonant, such as in "An honest mistake." Note that the reverse can also be true, as in "He gave a eulogy at the wake." The pronunciation is key.

Comment: @user1473511. *Honest* does not begin with a consonant **sound**. *Eulogy* begins with the sound /j/, which is felt to be a consonant when it is at the beginning of a word.

Comment: Nice way to find the answer

Comment: -1 I don't think people are going to write *a obligatory.* But many people use *a obligatory* when speaking, just as *a apple* and so forth. What does an ngram have anything to do with choice of indefinite article *for pronunciation!!*!!??

Answer (score 0):

I think an important point is that you "see" this but it "sounds ... unnatural".

The pronoun was invented for pronunciation.  It prevents the speaker from having to separate the vowels.

Since it is not necessary to speak while typing, I suggest that "a obligatory" is an Internet artifact.

Comment: I think you mean *article*, not *pronoun*

Answer (score 0):

The indefinite article "a" changes to "an" when used before a word that begins with a, e, i, o, or short u, ignoring any silent consonants.

Use "a" for long u, whether it's spelled "eu" or just with a "u."

Only use "an" for words that begin with "y" if it's with an initial "y" that sounds like a short i.  Words like this are very rare, nonetheless, listen to this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8oYgabMdIQ).  (an ytterbium element)

Use "a" for *w* and phrases beginning with *one/once*

> an honest mistake
>
> a universal trait
>
> an ugly duckling
>
> a euphoric feeling
>
> a one-time pad
>
> an only child
>
> a yes-man
>
> an iatrophoic person
>
> an idiot
>
> a wish upon a star

So, *an obligatory ...* etc.